# csv import works for tiny test file, not for actual file, no errors, mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, upload

I've got a large-ish  .csv (300krows) call it medium.csv that I am trying to import into a MySQL table.   When I do my import command on medium.csv  I get in mysql workbench the feedback '0 rows affected', and no warnings, and the table is unaffected.

In trying to troubleshoot, I started working on a mini version of the csv, which I created by opening medium.csv in excel, and cutting and pasting the first 5 lines into a new file, tiny.csv.   That works fine:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USER_DATA;
CREATE TABLE USER_DATA (UID INT, INSTALL_DATE DATE, PLATFORM_TYPE VARCHAR(10), COUNTRY_TYPE VARCHAR(11));

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E:\\Heather Data\\H Docs\\test\\tiny.csv'
into table USER_DATA
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 lines
(uid,
@install_date,
platform_type,
country_type)
set 
install_date = str_to_date(@install_date, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

When I run this on medium.csv, which lives in the same folder,  processing time is used up, but nothing happens, Ig et no warnings, and the target table is unaffected.

Can you give me some hints about how to trouble shoot?  I am really puzzled why the tiny file works and the medium one doesn't.

Would an error in the column data types or the file format of medium.csv cause this behaviour?

Is there an alternative import method I could use, if I can't troubleshoot this method?

thanks for any advice you can offer,

Heather

Comment: does medium.csv croak after 60 seconds?

Comment: as problem is not known, so you can try some different ways to figure out this problem. 1) change wait_timeout variable in your session to some high no. if set low numbers. 2) Also can check from gui like sqlyog may it give you some clue. 3) also can check after increasing max_allowed_packet variable size.

Comment: I've got it to work by relaxing some specification on the medium input file,  I dropped the enclosed by and terminated by.     Whew.    So perhaps there is a format issue that is being resolved by round tripping the tiny.csv into and out of excel.   Or there is a format issue occurring later in the file.

Comment: In other environments I've worked with there has always been a safe vanilla way of creeping up on file contents with dodgy structure, e.g. reading as string then casting.   not sure how this is typically dealt with in a MySQL context?  by preprocessing in some other environment?

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to run the following to view timeout periods active on your system.

```
SELECT @@global.wait_timeout, 
@@global.interactive_timeout, 
@@session.wait_timeout, 
@@session.interactive_timeout;
```

If they are set too low, such at 60 (seconds), then after that time period mysql will deem the operation as taking too long and terminate it. So if you are in the middle an update or load statement, which by itself is a transaction, it will fail and nothing will occur (as it is a transaction).

On hosted environments like GoDaddy, your choices are to whittle-down the size of any one batch, since you are unable to change server configuration.

On systems under your control as root, changes can be made to server environment to increase the amount of time mysql permits a long-running query to finish.

Options

A. **Global-level** meaning all new connections inherit the timeout values
Changes can be made to /etc/my.cnf

```
wait_timeout = 600
interactive_timeout = 600
```

Those are 10 minute values and will only come live after a mysql restart.

That edit can be performed without reboot, but having their thrust in-force now by performing:

```
mysql -uroot -p -e"SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=600; SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=600;"
```

or

B. **Connection-level** tweaking that vanish upon disconnect. Often good for making changes and un-changes wrapping time lengthy routines.

set @@wait_timeout=1000 -- a change to session wait_timeout

at end of connection, session wait_timeout is forgotten if modified and values default back to global upon re-connect.

Comment: really useful, i will check this out.  could be the format relax permitted it to run inside the time fence!   and it wasn't the format that fixed it after all.   I am running in a windows environment (yeah, I know! ;-) - and interacting via mysql workbench.   Not sure how to change config via that - will try to figure it out.  tx!   p.s.  What did you mean by 10 minute values in 3600?  what is 3600 equivalent to in old money (i.e. more std time notation). nb I upvoted will accept if it proves to be the issue.

Comment: sometimes the default is 28800 = 24 hours

Comment: yes, I'm running with the 28800 defaults atm, so plenty of time.  so I am suspecting the format issue again.   to feel really comfortable I should probably preprocess the file, as then I would know what was going on...

Comment: i suspected my gibberish had nothing to do with it. keep it on your shelf for another system !